# How to parse this JSON on android volley

Tags: android, json

Here is the output that I need to parse. The values of `usertype_name` should be stored into a String array. Please help me out.

```
{
    0: {
    usertype_name: "Member-Individual"
    },
    1: {
    usertype_name: "Member-Institutional"
    },
    2: {
    usertype_name: "Officer-Member"
    },
    3: {
    usertype_name: "Officer-Admin"
    },
    4: {
    usertype_name: "Officer-President"
    },
    current_position: "Member-Individual"
}
```

When parsing JSON on volley, normally I just do it like this:

```
public void onResponse(String s) {
    JSONArray array= new JSONArray(s.toString());
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
        String text = object.getString("usertype_name");
    }
}
```

But since there are incremental numbers showing on the result, which are weird for me, makes it confusing. Let me also post my webservice code. It goes like this, the `usertype_name` are results of a query and the `current_position` is a result of another query. If I'll remove the `current_position`, the numbers will disappear.

```
$result = mysql_result(mysql_query($query),0);
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);

while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $results[] = $line;
    }
$results['current_position'] = $result;

echo (json_encode($results));
```

Comment: Yeah... You are going to have to add more data. Where is your code? Are you using Volley already? Show it.

Comment: Actually... That isn't valid JSON. Integers and plain-text can't be keys.

Comment: Please check my edit. Hope it helps

Comment: Not really because you don't have valid JSON

Comment: How would I make it a valid JSON while keeping the `current_position` value?

Comment: Read the documentation on [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). It looks like you need an associative array. I'm not sure what the mysql result is giving you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your json string like this ,

```
{
  "array": [
    "Member-Individual",
    "Member-Institutional",
    "Officer-Member"
  ],
  "current_position": "6"
}
```

And the php code example :

```
 <?php
    class User {
        public $array = array("Member-Individual", "Member-Institutional", "Officer-Member");
        public $current_position = "6";

        public function __construct() {

        }
    }



    $user = new User();

    echo json_encode($user);
?>
```

Comment: can you help me on how to do that on php? I'm not familiar on that :(

Comment: Refer http://nitschinger.at/Handling-JSON-like-a-boss-in-PHP/

Comment: I have edited the answer . please have a look.